# Core plot ios - Adding same color shades to piechart

Tags: ios

I am using core plot in iPhone application. Currently I am getting different color for each slice in piechart. Is it possible to display single colour with different shades in piechart ?

For eg: 
[I need to get exactly like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyFYd.png)
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can add different colour for different shade as you can get Hex colour code from that colour shade

Comment: I used [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4] atPosition:0.9], Using this I can get different colors. Instead I need to get same like which I mentioned earlier (only blue color but with different shades)